# Optional "omitempty" when marshalling XML?

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I'm trying to generate XML for the Alfred 2 application. Looks kinda like this:

```
<items>
    <item autocomplete="My Thing">
        <title>My Thing</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>My Other Thing</title>
    </item>
    <item autocomplete="">
        <title>My Third Thing</title>
    </item>
</items>
```

The specific challenge I'm facing is that Alfred behaves differently if the `autocomplete` attribute on `item` is missing than if it is set to an empty string.

As a result, I'd like to be able to offer both possibilities: omit the attribute by default (`omitempty`), but offer the possibility to force it to be set to an empty string (*not* `omitempty`).

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointers in the struct you are going to marshal. In case the pointer is `nil` the field will be omitted. In case it is pointing to a string it will be rendered (even if the string is empty).

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/w6wUDSmwbo)

```
type Address struct {
    City *string
}

city1 := "NYC"
city2 := ""
address1 := Address{&city1}
address2 := Address{&city2}
address3 := Address{nil}

enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

enc.Encode(address1) // <Address><City>NYC</City></Address>
enc.Encode(address2) // <Address><City></City></Address>
enc.Encode(address3) // <Address></Address>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to avoid doing this, as almost every value is a string, so the API would be a repellent mess of pointers to strings. I think I'm going to have to generate the XML "by hand".